# Show indeterminate horizontal progressBar on the actionBar, like on PullToRefresh libraries

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

### Background

I wish to show an indeterminate progress bar that won't interrupt the user. I wish it to avoid having a progressDialog, a progress bar on the middle of the screen or a progress bar on an action item of the action bar.

For this, I wish to show a horizontal progress bar as shown on libraries like the [**PullToRefresh**](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) as shown [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOYtPF-4RPg) (and it even exists on google plus app) , but I don't want to have the library and not the ability to scroll to refresh.

### The problem

It's quite hard to find where is the relavant code in the third party libraries.

### What I've tried

Since I use [**ActionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), I've tried the next code:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    ...
    getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

This works, but it shows an indeterminate progressBar as an action bar item.

So I've tried to customize the style used on this activity:

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
>     <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="honeycomb">@style/MyActionBar</item>
>     <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
>     <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="IndeterminateProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"></style>
> ```

This seems to have done nothing of use.

### The question

Is it possible to update the style and that's it?
Has anyone used third party libraries to achieve this ?